# How to obtain glyphs from the "Apple Symbols" font in Lion?

Tags: macos, font, unicode, font-book, character-map

I'd like to make use of the special iOS symbols found in Apple Symbols font, e.g. the "Reload" and "Action" glyphs. In Snow Leopard, I could obtain and insert them via the "special characters" pane where I could show (and select!) *all* the symbols of any given font. In Lion, however, this feature seems to be missing (said pane now only contains some given character ranges) and when I preview the entire font repertoire in font-book, I can't select and insert text from the preview area.

Is there a way to obtain those symbols in a copyable form (i.e. to insert them into another application) on Lion?

Comment: May you show a screenshot of those characters?

Comment: Yes - the FontBook app still shows a sample of these font renderings, but getting to the specific unicode replacements requires you to let us know exactly which glyph you seek.

Comment: You can no longer do: **view:all characters** in Character Viewer ??  I don't have Lion yet, so maybe that's good.

Comment: It's e.g. character ID 5103 in Apple Symbols according to Font Book.app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snow Leopard's CharacterPalette.app still works on 10.7:

[image]

Those "iOS symbols" shown in the screenshot above are glyph variants that are specific to Apple Symbols. For example the turned arrow icon is a variant of Ꮿ. There doesn't seem to be any way to show them in 10.7's Character Viewer.

You could also use Font Book to save a PDF file for all characters in a font:

[image]

Comment: How can I obtain Snow Leopard's CharacterPalette.app on Lion?

Comment: http://cl.ly/1a0j3W380c0A0E341Q3d

Comment: Thank you! First the digital colour meter and now this, I don't know why Apple removed these useful features from simple applications.

Answer (score 0):

### [PopChar X](http://www.ergonis.com/products/popcharx/)

costs €30, which is expensive, but it will do what you need. You can download a trial version.

Comment: There is a free trial of this software - perhaps MrMage can get an answer while evaluating the trial.

Comment: I'd prefer not to pay 30 bucks for a feature that was free under SL.

Comment: Actually it's 30 euros, not 30 bucks. Like I said, expensive.

Comment: I couldn't find any way to show glyph variants, like those "iOS icons" in Apple Symbols.